# Pentaho CDE NewMapComponent doesn't show markers description tooltip

Tags: dictionary, pentaho, dashboard, cdf

I am trying to build a map using the pentaho CDE NewMapComponent (OpenStreet engine). Everything is working great, however i'm having problems adding the description tooltip for each marker.

I'm using a sql datasource, with a column for latitude, longitude, marker, and finally another column named 'description' as it is described in the NewMapComponent.js in comments. 
All columns seem to work fine, except the description.
Also, the FullMapTest example doesn't show any description as tooltip when passing the mouse over the markers.
Additionally in the file NewMapComponent.js, the lines 629 to 647 corresponding to the description tooltip code are commented.
I've tried to uncomment this code, but then the markers aren't even rendered. 
The log doesn't give me any errors.

I'm using Chrome, but tried to run this dashboard on other browsers with same result.
My bi-server version is 4.8.
Am I the only one with this problem? Should I do anything for the description tooltip to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this helps you in any ways http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?141559-Edit-Tooltip-in-CDE-dashboard